# Unusual tapered div design

Tags: css, html

How can I achieve a design like this with CSS3. I tried to give it a very high transparent border but that makes the taper outwards and not inwards.

It looks like something that can be achieved with CSS that is why I am reluctant to use images for this.

[image]

Comment: can you supply any code you have currently please. Does the div have a gradient that runs the entire back?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `:before` and `:after` to 'cover' parts of your gradient'ed `div`.

The problem is that borders dont support '%' as standard. So you'll have to use `@media` queries if your div needs to be responsive to change out the width of the borders, like below.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7njZd/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="angled"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#angled{
    background: #6393c1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 0%, #cfe7fa 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6393c1), color-stop(100%,#cfe7fa));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 0%,#cfe7fa 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 0%,#cfe7fa 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 0%,#cfe7fa 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6393c1 0%,#cfe7fa 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6393c1', endColorstr='#cfe7fa',GradientType=0 );
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
#angled:before,
#angled:after{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content:" ";
    height:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
#angled:after{
    border:30px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-width:0;
    border-left-width:200px;
    border-left-color:white;
}
#angled:before{
    border:60px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-width:0;
    border-right-width:300px;
    border-right-color:white;
}
@media (min-width:800px){
    #angled{
        width:800px;
    }
    #angled:after{
        border-left-width:350px;
    }
    #angled:before{
        border-right-width:450px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1200px){
    #angled{
        width:1200px;
    }
    #angled:after{
        border-left-width:500px;
    }
    #angled:before{
        border-right-width:700px;
    }
}
```

gradient generated using [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Perfecto!! I really get confused with pseudo :before and :after in cases like these. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The below should give you a starting point, the key is creating triangles using the borders of a `div`s `:before` and :`after` pseudo elements.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQVV6/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, div {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    background:#007bff;
}
div:before, div:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
}
div:before {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top:100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 200px 50px 0;
    border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}
div:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0 50px 400px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
}
```

Comment: I was going to go for `transform:rotate` but it is not a browser compatible +1

Comment: dang, you're just faster than me :P

Answer (score 1):

looks good so no?

I leave an example

**http://jsfiddle.net/jdQaA/1/**

```
    header{
    display:inline-block;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.main{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 1024px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height: 100px;
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    position:relative;
}

.main:before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 100px;
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
border-left: 924px solid #7db9e8;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.main:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0px;
height: 1px;
width: auto;
border-left: 100px solid #7db9e8;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.container{
    width: 1024px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.submain{
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
background: #7db9e8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7db9e8 0%, #1e5799 97%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7db9e8), color-stop(97%,#1e5799)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 97%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 97%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 97%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 97%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7db9e8', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


    margin-top: -25px;
}

.submain:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 1px;
    width: auto;
    border-right: 300px solid #7CB7E7;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
}
```